# Create ODBC Connection for Oracle from Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit PC

Tags: oracle, odbc

When I try to Create ODBC Connection for Oracle from my Windows 10 Pro 64 Bit PC , it show error 'Oracle client and network component not found'.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukZzn.png)

Comment: Did you install an Oracle (instant) client?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Oracle Documentation for this error:

*This error causes confusion when an Oracle client has been installed.  On 32-bit Windows it is enough to install the Oracle client to resolve the error.  However on 64-bit Windows you must first check if the process that throws the error is 32-bit or 64-bit, then install the 32-bit or 64-bit client accordingly.  I.E. If you are using a 32-bit application like Excel or Access and you have installed the 64-bit client then you will get this error.
This error will also be thrown if you are using a 64-bit application and have the 32-bit client installed.
Another scenario that can throw this error is if you are using Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) with SQL Server and SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).  Some parts of these products are 32-bit and some are 64-bit, and for all these to work together you will need to install BOTH the 32-bit AND the 64-bit Oracle clients.
To check if a process is 32-bit or 64-bit, open Task Manager via either Ctrl-Alt-Del or right-clicking on the task bar, then locate the process name in the Processes tab.  If there is a *32 after the process name then the process is 32-bit and will need the 32-bit Oracle client.  If *32 does not appear then the process is 64-bit and will need the 64-bit Oracle client.  (NB: This is only valid for 64-bit Windows.  On 32-bit Windows all processes are 32-bit and *32 will not be displayed in Task Manager.)*